# Ajaxical call to JSF backing bean method in JSF 1.0

Tags: ajax, jsf, dojo, backing-beans

Is it even possible to call a backing bean method using Ajax in a JSF 1.0 application and update the server side controls (dropdownlists) in server and push the changes to the client side?

I have no idea on how we could do that. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just upgrade to JSF 2.0? It exist almost 3 years already.

Comment: @BalusC : not possible to upgrade to JSF2.0 , I know there are AJAX calling mechanism,but have to stick with JSF1.0 , any ideas ?

Comment: @BalusC some companies have old legacy code which cannot be migrated to a newer version without investing years of manpower.